# How to use driver.get() with string enum in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to use these enums with driver.get but it output as invalid argument. How to resolve this issue?
Here is my code:

```
public enum Url_1{
            URL_LOGIN("http://localhost/wordpress/wp-login.php"),
            URL_DASHBOARD("http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/"),
            URL_NEWPOST("http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/post-new.php"),
            URL_EDIT("http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/edit.php");
    
            public String url;
    
            private Url_1(String env_url){
                this.url = env_url;
            }
    
            public String getUrl(){
                return url;
            }
        }

public void setUp() {
        WebDriver driver = getDriver(Browser.CHROME);
        driver.get(String.valueOf(Url_1.URL_LOGIN));
}
```

Comment: driver.get(Url_1.URL_LOGIN.getUrl())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
driver.get(Url_1.URL_LOGIN.getUrl())
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the getter (public String getUrl()), because otherwise your output will be equal to the name of the enum constant (E.g.: URL_LOGIN, URL_DASHBOARD, etc.). getUrl will retrieve the contents held by those constants.